# WINRM not able to enable on windos machine from Latest Jenkins

Tags: windows, powershell, jenkins

I have a powershell script and I am using psexec/psservice to enable and restart winrm service.This was working fine with old version of Jenkins.But when I used below script in latest jenkins it says "PSexec.exe/PsService.exe is not a recognize command.

```
foreach ($computer in $fqdn) {
$result = winrm id -r:$computer 2> $null
    if ($lastExitCode -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "WinRM already enabled on" $computer "..." -ForegroundColor green
    } else {
    Write-Host "Enabling WinRM on" $computer "..." -ForegroundColor red 
      PsExec.exe \\$computer -accepteula -s C:\Windows\System32\winrm.cmd qc -quiet 

    if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) {
        PsService.exe \\$computer restart WinRM 
        $result  = winrm id -r:$computer 2>$null

    if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) {Write-Host "WinRM successfully enabled!" -ForegroundColor green}
        else {Write-Host "WinRM not enabled!" -ForegroundColor red}

       } #end of if

    } #end of else  
} #end of foreach
```

Can any one help me here and let me know why this happens ? The script works fine when I am executing outside Jenkins.

Comment: Likely, it can't find `psexec.exe` in any of the folders in the `PATH` variable. Possibly because of 32/64 bit issues. The easiest answer is to give the full path to where `psexec.exe` is located.

Comment: I have tried giving full path as well. But same error I am getting.I am able to execute the script directly from powershell, but issue when using Jenkins.IS there any settings need to change on Jenkins ?

Comment: Hello. Maybe you shud try this: Start-Process "D:\Proj\PsExec.exe" -ArgumentList {\\Hostname cmd /c C:\Windows\System32\winrm.cmd qc -quiet}

Comment: Thanks Vitaly, that works for me